# how to generate a short id to use as key on dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I need to create IDs to use as key on DynamoDB. Checked https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid but the ids generated are too long to be remembered. how can I generate shorter ones like the ones from youtube video Id.

Also do I really need to specify a Key or Dynamo can create one automatically for me just like firebase firestore for example?

My code:

```
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var student = {
  TableName: "students",
  Item: {
    id: "abc123",
    name: "Mia",
  },
};

db.put(student)
  .promise()
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Yes you need to specify a key. I'm fact that's literally the least amount of info you CAN specify to create a record. There are only two keys possible on each record. A partitionKey and a sortKey. They need to be unique when considered together for a record to be found. There's a lot of nuance there to catch up on if you're not up to speed so I can't won't get into it here.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are saying sorry

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to build a URL Shortener.  There are loads of tutorials online showcasing how to do this in AWS using DynamoDB and API Gateway, so you might want to search online for a more detailed walkthrough.

> how can I generate shorter ones like the ones from youtube video Id

You'll need to generate this yourself in your application code.  If you're using javascript, you could use something like this, which creates a random string:

```
  let short_id = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
```

Keep in mind that you'll need to include retry logic in the event the generated ID is *not* unique in the database.

> do I really need to specify a Key or Dynamo can create one automatically for me just like firebase firestore for example?

DynamoDB will not automatically create or manage ID's for your application.  You'll need to do this yourself.

Comment: I’m not looking for a url shortener. I want to give my students a simple ids they can remember

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I read into your requirement since it sounded like you needed a short url that was easy to remember.  Even so, I'd suggest the same pattern as a url shortener.  You create an ID that matches your criteria (short, easy to remember, etc).  DynamoDb won't create IDs for you, so you'll need to do that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nanoid` which is similar to uuid, u can use specify length of ID u want

```js
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid')

var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var student = {
  TableName: "students",
  Item: {
    id: nanoid(), // or nanoid(10) for 10 char id
    name: "Mia",
  },
};

db.put(student)
  .promise()
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```